# Make a custom hyperlink in php

Tags: php

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   $count = 0 ;
   echo "<form action="index{$count}.html" id='frmSignIn'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='form-group align-center' >
                    <div class='col-md-10'>
                        <label><b>".$row['docname']."</b></label>
                        <label><b>".$row['pname']."</b></label>
                        <label><b>".$row['date']."</b></label>
                        <label><b>".$row['medicine']."</b></label>
                        <input type='submit'value='Get Medicines' class='form-control input-lg align-center' name='l_uname'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>";
    $count++ ;
}
```

Now my requirement is when count=0 index0.html should open , when count = 1 index1.html should open. I have tried many solutions but none of them are working. This is basically string concatenation issue i guess. what can be the best way to solve it..

Comment: `$count++` and `'index{$count}.html'`

Comment: the problem is the quotes! `"` inside a string `"string....."quotes"...more text"` won't work

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the output was from your code sample?  Have you tried adding some debugging statements?

Comment: either make it `action='index{$count}.html'` or `action='index".$count.".html'`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'index' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\presdisp.php on line 39 This is the error i am getting 39 is that line of action.

Comment: @jeff is it not possible to put that quotes in singe quote and that might work somehow...Like..."string.....'quotes'..more text"

Comment: it is possible, see my second comment.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's how you should do it. Just do as @Jeff suggests and you will be set.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<form action=index".$count.".html id='frmSignIn'>
```